# How to compute an integral involving the error function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, error-function

Solving a problem with one dimensional diffusion the following identity naturally arises

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{q}{2}{{\rm e}^{\eta\,t{\alpha}^{2}-\alpha
\,x}} \left( 
{{\rm erf}\left({\frac {-2\,\alpha\,\eta\,t+x+a}{2\sqrt {\eta t}}}\right)}
+
{{\rm erf}\left({\frac {2\,\alpha\,\eta\,t-x+a}{2\sqrt {\eta t}}}\right)}
 \right) {dx}=-{\frac {q \left( -{{\rm e}^{\alpha\,a}}+{{\rm e}^{-
\alpha\,a}} \right) }{\alpha}}
$$

Please let me know how to prove such identity directly.